# Reason for LinqToQuerystring attibute: LinqToQueryable

Tags: linq, attributes, asp.net-web-api2

There is an attribute (LinqToQueryable) in the webapi package for LinqToQuerystring, but I wasn't able to find a good explanation how it works.

- Does it modify the returning results?
- Does it enable LinqToQuerystring? (but how do I get the querystring then?)
- Other?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the attribute [LinqToQueryable] filters/orders/... the Queryable result when returning.

To get the querystring in webapi2 I created an extension method:

```
public static class RequestExtensions
{
    public static string GetQueryString(this HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Select(x => x.Key + "=" + x.Value).Aggregate((i, j) => i + "&" + j);
    }
}
```

But I suspect this could also be done with ODataRequestOptions as parameter for the (webapi)method instead of using the querystring. The only problem is I don't know how to convert this to a string.
The advantage for this ODataRequestOption is that you can easily couple validators.

Comment: You could have also used Request.RequestUri.Query.